# iOS Realm: How do i downcast to Object

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a protocol:

```
protocol DatabaseProtocol {
    func getObjects<T>(_: T.Type) -> [T]
}
```

Then i implement this protocol:

```
class RealmDatabase: Database {
    func getObjects<T>(object: T) -> [T] {
      //how can i return here the objects from realm?
         return realm.objects(T)
    }
}
```

And i dont want to change the protocol to restrict to < T: Object>, since i want to be able to change to another Database,and Object inherits from realm.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE #1**

I also tried this:

```
func getObjects<T>(object: T) -> [T] {
    let result = realm.objects(object as Object).map { $0 }
    return result
}
```

Then i get 'cannot convert value of type 'T' to type Object in coercion'

Answer (score 1):

```
func getObjects<T>(t: T.Type) -> [T] {
    return realm.objects(t as! Object.Type).map { $0 as! T }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.

Generic T needs to inherit from RealmSwift.Object

```
func add<T: Object>(_ object: T) -> Result<Void, Error> {
    return realmResult.flatMap { realm -> Result<Void, Error> in
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(object, update: false)
            }
            return .success()
        } catch {
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I think the better way is your protocol should make an associatedtype object, like:

```
protocol DatabaseProtocol {
    associatedtype T: RealmSwift.Object
    func getObjects(_ object: T) -> [T]
}
```